# Study instability of a system with Lyapunov functions in terms of a parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I am given the following system of odes
\begin{gather}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix} - 
b(x^2 + y^2) \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix} +
(x^2 + y^2)^2 \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
I want to study the stability of the $(0, 0)$ solution in terms of $b$.
I cannot understand the argument they are using. It goes as follows:
\begin{equation}
V(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)
\end{equation}
is a Lyapunov function for $(0, 0)$ under certain conditions. Exactly,

1. $V(0, 0) = 0$
2. $\dot{V}(x, y) = DV(x,y) f(x, y) = \\ 
    = x(y-bx(x^2+y^2) + x(x^2+y^2)^2) + y(-x -by(x^2+y^2)+y(x^2+y^2)^2) = \\
    = -b (x^2+y^2)^2 + (x^2+y^2)^3$

Then, if $b>0$ for all $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2 < \sqrt{b}$ we have that $\dot{V} < 0$, therefore $V$ is a strict Lyapunov function and the solution $(0,0)$ is asymptotically stable.

If $b \leq 0$ then $\dot{V} > 0$ for all $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$, **therefore it is inestable (because if time goes the other way it would be asymptotically stable).**

The parts I am not understanding are in bold.

First of all, when we talk about stability I thought solutions only needed to be defined for positive time. Therefore, by time "going the other way", what do we mean? Are we considering $-t$? Also, I don't see why this would mean instable.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A book that might be of interest to you is BHATIA, N. P. & SZEGO, G. P. (1970) Stability Theory of Dynamical Systems, Springer-Verlag, New York. They study stability of dynamical systems for $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the limit of the states as time, denoted by $t$, goes to $-\infty$. This is equivalent to first defining a new "time-variable" $\tau = -t$ and look at the limit at $\tau \to \infty$, with

$$
\frac{d\,V(x,y)}{d\tau} = \frac{d\,V(x,y)}{dt} \frac{d\,t}{d\tau} = -\frac{d\,V(x,y)}{dt}.
$$

From this it is hopefully clear that for $b \leq 0$ it follows that as $\tau \to \infty$ and thus $t \to -\infty$, then the state goes to the origin. So as time $t$ becomes more negative the states get closer to the origin. Therefore, as time $t$ becomes more positive the states get further from the origin, which is equivalent to the origin of the system being unstable.

It can be noted that this is not a necessary condition for instability. Namely, an equilibrium point of a system is also considered unstable when only some of its state diverge from the considered equilibrium point. Instead one could use [Chetaev's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chetaev_instability_theorem) to more generally determine instability.